# Why datepicker not appearing in my datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datepicker, datagridcell

Why datepicker is not appearing in my datagrid.
I have textblock, one datepicker and then again textblock in total three columns, Those two textblocks appears properly but the datepicker do not appear. whereas there is no problem in binding because if a have applied same in the listview and there they are appearing, it's something wrong i have done in xaml in datagrid which i am not able to figure it out. I want user to select dates from this datepicker.

Below is my code, what i am missing any idea ?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ColumnWidth="*"    
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EquipMaintCollection}" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexOfItem}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaintElement}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="{x:Static res:LocalizedString.Name}" />
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MainteDue">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker x:Name="MainteDue" SelectedDate="{Binding MainteDue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MainteDue,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>       
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Until Due" Width="*" MinWidth="100" Foreground="{Binding UntilDue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToRedBrushConverter}}" Binding="{Binding Path=UntilDue}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Other than your DataGrid having AutoGenerateColumns specified twice (are you sure you're compiling correctly? :)), your xaml works fine for me.. the datepicker appears when i double click a cell.

Comment: It actually works fine for me too. If you want to show the DatePicker always and not just on editing, you should put it in the CellTemplate replacing the TextBlock with the DatePicker like you do in the CellEditingTemplate